# Regular expressions

Tags: regex, parsing, erlang

I have text file. I try to parse it in erlang.

Text format:

```
pattern1 : value1
pattern2 : value2
pattern3 : value3
...
```

What regular expressions to parse this file? I need key-value list in output:

```
[{pattern1 : value1}, {pattern1 : value1}, {pattern1 : value1}].
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why can't you just read in data until the `:`, call that the key, and then read until the newline and call that the value?

Comment: Why not splitting the string by lines, and then each line by `:`? I don't know Erlang, but it should be very simple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On top of my head:

```
foo() ->
    {ok, Fd} = file:open("file.txt", [read]),
    process_lines(Fd, file:read_line(Fd), []).

process_lines(_, eof, Acc) -> Acc;
process_lines(Fd, {ok, Line}, Acc) ->
    [Pattern, Value] = string:tokens(Line, " :\n"),
    process_lines(Fd, file:read_line(Fd), [{Pattern,Value}|Acc]).
```

I haven't tested this code but something like that should work.